# Is ICreateDevEnum from DirectShow missing in Windows CE?

Tags: windows-ce, directshow, missing-features

I am looking for the ICreateDevEnum usually in strmiids.lib and declared in strmids.h
but it looks like it is missing in the DirectShow on Windows CE.

Is it true or is it maybe relocated somewhere else ?

Comment: Presumably, device enumeration support is not included in Win CE

Comment: Dear Mr. Roman I saw you are an expert of DirectShow. May I kindly ask you to contact you directly regarding my DirectShow problems, please ?

Comment: Well, finding my email address through profile and website is not a very difficult quest :)

Comment: Thank you, but I found it on your site, tried it but am receiving "Delivery Status Notification (Failure)". Do not want to put your address in public so I am putting mine. If you can reach me I will contact you back.  (patrik.fatoric@gmail.com)